# Why are the values in my dynamic 2D char array being overwritten?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, dynamic, realloc

I'm trying to build a process logger in C on Linux, but having trouble getting it right. I'd like it to have 3 colums: USER, PID, COMMAND. I'm using the output of `ps aux` and trying to dynamically append it to an array. That is, for every line `ps aux` outputs, I want to add a row to my array.

This is my code. (To keep the output short, I only grep for sublime. But this could be anything.)

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char** processes = NULL;
    char* substr = NULL;
    int n_spaces = 0;
    int columns = 1;

    char line[1024];
    FILE *p;
    p = popen("ps -eo user,pid,command --sort %cpu | grep sublime", "r");
    if(!p)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line) - 1, p))
    {
        puts(line);
        substr = strtok(line, " ");
        while(substr != NULL)
        {
            processes = realloc(processes, sizeof(char*) * ++n_spaces);

            if(processes == NULL)
                exit(-1);

            processes[n_spaces - 1] = substr;

            // first column user, second PID, third all the rest
            if(columns < 2)//if user and PID are already in array, don't split anymore
            {
                substr = strtok(NULL, " ");
                columns++;
            }
            else
            {
                substr = strtok(NULL, "");
            }
        }
        columns = 1;
    }
    pclose(p);

    for(int i = 0; i < (n_spaces); i++)
        printf("processes[%d] = %s\n", i, processes[i]);

    free(processes);

    return 0;

}
```

The output of the for loop at the end looks like this.

```
processes[0] = user
processes[1] = 7194
processes[2] = /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 27184

processes[3] = user
processes[4] = 7194
processes[5] = /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 27184

processes[6] = user
processes[7] = 27194
processes[8] = /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 27184

processes[9] = user
processes[10] = 27194
processes[11] = /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 27184
```

But, from the `puts(line)` I get that the array should actually contain this:

```
user       5016 sh -c ps -eo user,pid,command --sort %cpu | grep sublime
user       5018 grep sublime
user      27184 /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
user      27194 /opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 27184
```

So, apparently all the values are being overwritten and I can't figure out why... (Also, I don't get where the value `7194` in `processes[0] = 7194` and `processes[4] = 7194` comes from).

What am I doing wrong here? Is it somehow possible to make the output look like the output of `puts(line)`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no 2D array here. You have a 1D array of pointers. For each pointer, allocate a chunk of memory and copy the read sub string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `strtok` is a pointer into the string that you tokenise. (The token has been made null-terminated by overwriting the first separator after it with `'\0'`.)

When you read a new line with `fgets`, you overwrite the contents of this line and all tokens, not just the ones from the last parsing, point to the actual content of the line. (The pointers to the previous tokens remain valid, but the content at these locations changes.)

The are several ways to fix this.

- You could make the tokens you save arrays of chars and `strcpy` the parsed contents.
- You could duplicate the parsed tokens with (the non-standard) `strdup`,  which allocates memory for the strings on the heap.
- You could read an array of lines, so that the tokens are really unique.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried the `strdup` way and it works! Just another question: what would be the fastest (in terms of execution time) method?

Comment: It's hard to tell which method is the fastest. Repeated allocation takes some time (and therefore your reallocation of `processes` for each string should be slow), but in your example I expect the external calls to be more crucial to performance than how you store the strings. The `strdup` variant is certainly the most flexible mathod, but remember to `free` the duplicated strings later.

Comment: Where should I free the duplicated strings? After the while loop (just like     `free(processes)`)?
Is there an alternative to `popen()` and maybe an alternative to `ps` to increase performance? Perhaps without using external calls?

Comment: In your case, you should free the strings just before you free the containing array, `processes`. Remember that after freeing `proccesses`, its contents are no longer valid, so you have to do it before that. The destruction (`free`) has the reverse order of creation (`malloc`). In general, you free stuff when you don't need it any longer, which usually is at the end of a function.

Comment: As for performance: I wouldn't worry about that too much right now. Build a stable, understandable program. Only if the performance is dreadful you should start looking into that.

Comment: I'm just asking because I'd like this running on Android, but I don't think it's possible to use `popen`, so do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Android, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` returns a pointer into the string it processes. That string is, always, stored in the variable `line`. So all your pointers in the array point to the same place in memory.

As @Lundin wrote in a comment, there is no two-dimensional array here, just a one-dimensional array of pointers.